# Ruby on Rails devise return role of user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I included a few roles for users using a very simple method I found for the devise gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-a-default-role-to-a-User

But now on the users profile page I cannot figure out how to display the user's assigned role, let alone being able to change it. I've been trying variations on `<%= current_user.role %>` in the actual view but nothings worked to display my user's role type. Here's how its set up:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :role
  before_create :set_default_role
  private
    def set_default_role
      self.role ||= Role.find_by_name('contractor')
    end
end
```

role.rb

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :users
end
```

seeds.rb

```
['contractor', 'employer', 'business', 'admin'].each do |role|
    Role.find_or_create_by_name role
end
```

UPDATE:

after more messing around I found that

```
<%= Role.where(current_user.id).name %>
<%= Role.where('role_id = ?', current_user.id).name %>
```

both return the same thing "Role" but shouldn't it return something like "contractor" instead?
ps. here is the migration for create_roles.rb:

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Update 2:

I realized I added the role id to the user record as the tutorial said. Migration:

```
class AddRoleIdToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role_id, :integer
  end
end
```

So I changed my code around to

```
<%= User.where("role_id = 'contractor'").name %>
```

and that returns "User" how weird! I am brand new to this language and web development in general but I just want it to return my 'contractor' or 'employer' role type. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is final solutions? can you please write here.. i have same issue. Please do needful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do well using the [`delegate`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) method

---

**Other Model Data**

Problem is, you're trying to load another model's data object into your current model. This would have to work like this:

```
@user.role.name # -> "role" is another object, not a naked piece of data
```

The way around this will be to add this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to :role
  delegate :name, to: :role, prefix: true #-> yields @user.role_name

  before_create :set_default_role
  private
    def set_default_role
      self.role ||= Role.find_by_name('contractor')
    end
end
```

---

**Relational Data**

If you're beginning with Rails (welcome, by the way), you should look into how [relational database structures](http://oreilly.com/ruby/excerpts/ruby-learning-rails/intro-ruby-relational-db.html) work

Essentially, you do everything with `id`'s (called a [`primary_key`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key)). This allows different models to call data from related models by calling the respective ID's. That's why you had to add `role_id` to your user model

I think you'll benefit from learning about how to use the data objects called back from the relational models. I.E `@user.role_id` will have to be a corresponding ID of the `roles` db

Comment: thank you, I added in the delegate but and added in @user.role.name but it still doesn't work, it said: "NoMethodError in Dashboard#index ... undefined method 'role' for nil:NilClass" it seems to be looking in my controller for `def role` which is strange to me. I also tried it with "current_user.role.name" but that gave a different error. I read the relational data - I think I understand the concept the the syntax is hard to capture for me. maybe its the devise gem that is throwing me off.

Comment: Devise just creates a session for the logged in user - the saved data is still the same. In your `user` table, do you have the `role_id` column populated? If so, is the value of that column correspondent with a column in the roles db?

Comment: In terms of the `nil:NilClass` error, how are you creating the `@user` var? If you have your associations set up correctly, you shouldn't have to reference the `Role` model directly at all - you could do this: `@user = User.find(5) @user.role.name` to bring back the role name :)

Comment: Sorry that took a minute, I had to download a .sqlite3 viewer. so I checked and my users table has role_id, but its not populated! I assumed it was because I had the set_default_role code I don't understand why its not assigning a role to my users. Also, roles table is totally blank. I'm not sure what to do, I'll drop the database, restart server and register again to see what happens

Comment: ok, so I did that and it didn't fill out my role_id collumn on my new login I just created. so I don't know why because all the relevant code is there. Also, I don't know how I'm created the @user var or even if I am - I thought devise did all that for me and so far to get the users email and things I just write current_user.email and it works fine.

Comment: The roles db will have to be populated by you - just run the Rails console (`rails c`) and then type `Role.create(name: "Contractor")` for as many roles as you wish to create

Comment: `current_user` is okay - I used `@user` as an example only! `current_user` should load the relevant `role` depending on whether you have the Roles table setup

Comment: Thanks Rich! I'll try that tomorrow, I really appreciate your advice here!

Comment: What is final solutions? can you please write here.. i have same issue. Please do needful

Comment: This was so long ago I don't remember but I've downloaded this old application from github to see if I could figure out what I had done. so far no luck but you can look at it if you want: https://github.com/LegitMiller/EQsamp I created this using an old version of rails though. It might have been something as simple as missing the permissions to change the attributes in the controller. I don't know, sorry I couldn't be more help!